# Shell: list directories ordered by file count (including in subdirectories)

Tags: linux, unix, shell, command-line

I've nearly reached my limit for the permitted number of files in my Linux home directory, and I'm curious about where all the files are.

In any directory I can use for example `find . -type f | wc -l` to show a count of how many files are in that directory and in its subdirectories, but what I'd like is to be able to generate a complete list of all subdirectories (and sub-subdirectories etc) each with a **count** of all files contained in it and *its* subdirectories - if possible ranked by count, descending.

Eg if my file structure looks like this:

```
Home/
  file1.txt
  file2.txt
  Docs/
    file3.txt
    Notes/
      file4.txt
      file5.txt
    Queries/
      file6.txt
  Photos/
    file7.jpg
```

The output would be something like this:

```
7  Home
4  Home/Docs
2  Home/Docs/Notes
1  Home/Docs/Queries
1  Home/Photos
```

Any suggestions greatly appreciated. (Also a quick explanation of the answer, so I can learn from this!). Thanks.

Comment: What makes you think you're nearing the limit of files *per directory*? Any limit of files per directory that I've aware of doesn't need to calculate files-per-subdirectories, only files directly in this directory... May be you've meant "inodes per partition"?

Comment: I think it's the total number of files I have on the system (that was the gist of the explanation given by the sysadmin...). What I want is to find if there's a big folder full of old cache files or logs or crash reports that I can delete.

Comment: ... as for instance 10000 files in a hidden folder named `.../.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.epp.usagedata.recording` - blimey!

Comment: `du ~/* | sort -n`  will give you a sorted list of directory sizes, which is likely to be useful also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
countFiles () {
    # call the recursive function, throw away stdout and send stderr to stdout
    # then sort numerically
    countFiles_rec "$1" 2>&1 >/dev/null | sort -nr
}

countFiles_rec () {
    local -i nfiles 
    dir="$1"

    # count the number of files in this directory only
    nfiles=$(find "$dir" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -print | wc -l)

    # loop over the subdirectories of this directory
    while IFS= read -r subdir; do

        # invoke the recursive function for each one 
        # save the output in the positional parameters
        set -- $(countFiles_rec "$subdir")

        # accumulate the number of files found under the subdirectory
        (( nfiles += $1 ))

    done < <(find "$dir" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -print)

    # print the number of files here, to both stdout and stderr
    printf "%d %s\n" $nfiles "$dir" | tee /dev/stderr
}


countFiles Home
```

produces

```
7 Home
4 Home/Docs
2 Home/Docs/Notes
1 Home/Photos
1 Home/Docs/Queries
```

Comment: Thanks glenn - sorry to be dense, but to use this do I need to put the function definitions in a file somewhere?

Comment: Yep. If you're writing a script, just add them to that file.

Comment: You don't even need to put it in a file, you can paste the function straight into your current prompt and bash will define the function for you.

Comment: Note, that this will work only for **bash**, not shell per se (sh reports syntax error for `done < <(find "$dir" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -print)'`)

Answer (score 46):

I use the following command

`find . -xdev -type f | cut -d "/" -f 2 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n`

Which produces something like:

```
[root@ip-***-***-***-*** /]# find . -xdev -type f | cut -d "/" -f 2 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
      1 .autofsck
      1 stat-nginx-access
      1 stat-nginx-error
      2 tmp
     14 boot
     88 bin
    163 sbin
    291 lib64
    597 etc
    841 opt
   1169 root
   2900 lib
   7634 home
  42479 usr
  80964 var
```

Comment: This seems to be the most efficient solution, as it does not fork a new process for every file to be counted, but rather processes a large stream of files with a single 'cut' command.

Answer (score 8):

This should work:

```
find ~ -type d -exec sh -c "fc=\$(find '{}' -type f | wc -l); echo -e \"\$fc\t{}\"" \; | sort -nr
```

Explanation:
In the command above will run "find ~ -type d" to find all the sub-directories the home-directory. For each of them, it runs a short shell script that finds the total number of files in that sub-directory (using the "find $dir -type f | wc -l" command that you already know), and will echo the number followed by the directory name. The sort command then runs to sort by the total number of files, in a descending order.

This is not the most efficient solution (you end up scanning the same directory many times), but I am not sure you can do much better with a one liner :-)

Comment: Thanks, that works, but it creates a very long list! Guess I should have asked if it's possible to list only the top 50 results...

Comment: Just add "| head -50" at the end.

Comment: Ooops, it worked when I tried it locally (on my laptop HD, as a test), but when I ssh into the server where I actually need it, I get an error: `Unmatched ".`

Comment: Maybe /bin/sh is not bash on your server? Try replacing 'sh' in the command above with 'bash'.

Comment: Most probably there are file or directory names that contain space characters. Try the `-print0' option for find.

Comment: @hochi: as in `find ~ -print0 -type d...` and `fc=\$(find '{}' -print0 -type f...`?

Answer (score 4):

simpler and more efficient:

```
find ~ -type f -exec dirname {} \; | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

Comment: This does not include subdirectory counts.

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c '(echo -n "{} "; ls {} | wc -l)' \; | sort -n -k 2
```

This is pretty efficient.

It will display the counts in ascending order (i.e. largest at the end). To get it is descending order, add the "-r" option to "sort".

If you run this command in the "/" directory, it will scan the entire filesystem and tell you what are the directories that contain the most files and sub-directories. It's a good way to see where all your inodes are being used.

Note: this will not work for directories that contain spaces, but you could modify it to work in that case, if it's a problem for you.

Answer (score 1):

See following example: sort by column 2 reversely. Use `sort -k 2 -r`. -k 2 means sort with column 2 (space separated), -r means reverse.

```
# ls -lF /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/165536.165536/aufs/mnt/ | sort -k 2 -r
total 972
drwxr-xr-x   65 165536   165536        4096 Jun  5 12:23 ad45ea3c6a03aa958adaa4d5ad6fc25d31778961266972a69291d3664e3f4d37/
drwxr-xr-x   19 165536   165536        4096 Jun  6 06:46 7fa7f957669da82a8750e432f034be6f0a9a7f5afc0a242bb00eb8024f77d683/
drwxr-xr-x    2 165536   165536        4096 May  8 02:20 49e067ffea226cfebc8b95410e90c4bad6a0e9bc711562dd5f98b7d755fe6efb/
drwxr-xr-x    2 165536   165536        4096 May  8 01:19 45ec026dd49c188c68b55dcf98fda27d1f9dd32f825035d94849b91c433b6dd3/
drwxr-xr-x    2 165536   165536        4096 Mar 13 06:08 0d6e95d4605ab34d1454de99e38af59a267960999f408f720d0299ef8d90046e/
drwxr-xr-x    2 165536   165536        4096 Mar 13 02:25 e9b252980cd573c78065e8bfe1d22f01b7ba761cc63d3dbad284f5d31379865a/
drwxr-xr-x    2 165536   165536        4096 Mar 13 02:24 f4aa333b9c208b18faf00b00da150b242a7a601693197c1f1ca78b9ab2403409/
drwxr-xr-x    2 165536   165536        4096 Mar 13 02:24 3946669d530695da2837b2b5ed43afa11addc25232b29cc085a19c769425b36b/
drwxr-xr-x    2 165536   165536        4096 Mar 11 11:11 44293f77f63806a58d9b97c3c9f7f1397b6f0935e236250e24c9af4a73b3e35b/
```

Answer (score -1):

If however you are fine with the non cumulative solution by using dirname (see answer of wjb) then by far more efficient is:

```
find ~ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 dirname | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

Note that this does not display empty dirs. For that you may do
    find ~ -type d -empty
if your version of find supports it.

Comment: Hmm, since dirname is there, path is missing. My guess is either xargs -0 does not work on your system, or you have files called " " or so, i.e the file name is just composed of whitespace. The latter is possible, but weird:

Comment: actually i've just tested with white space files / dirs ( touch " " and mkdir " " to create such weird stuff) and the command still works. However, the find -print0 | xargs -0 hasn't always been around cf : https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html .